# creating http link dynamically according to the user input

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am now building a webpage with a search box included. How to create a search query which changes according to the input on the search box?

```
<input type=text name="searchquery"/>
<input type=button name=search value="search" onClick=changeQuery()/>

changeQuery(){
????
}
```

Comment: where you want to place the link?

Comment: What does "create a search query" mean? Are you trying to fake submitting a form? What is wrong with just using a form?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman in an <iframe/> tag

Comment: @Quentin for example when user enters something on the text box then clicks search then search query in url bar changes something like https://www.google.co.in/search?q=search+query

Comment: then you can use the **windows.location.href = url +"/"+query**

Comment: @MOHANAVEL — So what is wrong with using a form? HTML has the solution built in. Using JavaScript just means writing code to do something the browser will already do for you.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman — Don't slap user input into a URL without escaping it.

Comment: @Quentin sorry for asking this! can i use <form name="customsearch" action=www.google.co.in/search?q=+ "doubt" > How to get the value of the text input right there in the place of "doubt"?

Comment: `<form action="http://www.google.co.in/search">`. You don't do anything to get the value of the input. Putting the value of the input there is the whole point of the form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow i managed to get the desired output...

```
<input type=text id='sq' name="searchquery"/>
<input type=button name=search value="search" onClick=changeQuery()/>

changeQuery(){
var input_query=document.getElementById('sq').value;
window.location="http://www.google.com/search?q="+input_query+"myString";
}
```